# How to loop through a file until nth delimiter and print the output

Tags: powershell

I have a file with multiple lines separated by a delimiter" |" 
In the below example I have 5 "|" delimiters. So there 6 messages. Now I want 3 messages.

InputFile.txt

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
|
Line4
Line5
|
Line6
|
Line7
|
Line8
Line9
|
Line10
```

Output:

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
|
Line4
Line5
|
Line6
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Please regard that StackOverflow is not a free code writing service, so you have to try it on your own, and when stuck, come back here with a specific question, providing a [mcve]! Read the [tour] and learn [ask] here! Starting point for a batch-file: commands [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html), [`if`](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html), [`set /A`](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html), [`echo`](http://ss64.com/nt/echo.html), [`goto`](http://ss64.com/nt/goto.html).

Comment: While the question shows no effort on the part of the OP to solve the problem, I don't think it's too broad - in combination with the title, the problem seems to be well-defined.

Comment: I have tried below but unsuccessful. Foreach ($line in $path){$linenumber++ for ($i=0; $i -lt 3; $i++)}

Comment: I disagree with it being closed as too broad, but @VijayAnand it would be best if you put the code you tried in the question, instead of burying it here in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to throw another option out there:

```
(Get-Content '.\InputFile.txt' -Raw).Split('|')[0..2] -join '|'
```

Comment: Nice one-liner. I didn't know you could select a range of indices within an array like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Get-Content` to get the lines of the file and output them line by line, using a for loop:

```
# Set the delimiter character and get the file contents
$delimiter = '|'
$content = Get-Content $filePath

# Loop over each line, set the delimiter count
$delimCount = 0
foreach( $line in $content ){

  # If the line equals the delimiter and the delimiter count is 3, exit the loop
  # ++$variable increments the variable by 1, then evaluates it
  # The right side of an -and is not evaulated if the left side is $False
  if( $line -eq $delimiter -and ++$delimCount -ge 3 ) {
    break;
  }

  # Output the line
  $line
}
```

Comment: Hi Bender thanks for ur effort . Appreciate it. But am unable to get the output . Getting the below error Unexpected token ')' in for loop statement

Comment: Guess Powershell doesn't like multiple assignments in a `for` loop. I changed the solution to use a `foreach` and just declare the delimiter count outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

#### Count up to the group marker, then quit.

```
$groupcount = 0

Get-Content -Path '.\InputFile.txt' |
    ForEach-object {
        if ($_ -eq '|') {
            $groupcount++
            if ($groupcount -eq 3) { break }
        }
        if ($groupcount -lt 3) { Write-Output $_ }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @lit, ur logic helped me to solve my problem but am getting a "|" at the end of the line.

Comment: @VijayAnand - You are correct. I have revised the code so that the separator does not appear at the end.